# Liferay: Where in the database are the community pages saved?

Tags: database, liferay

I need to find the table where community pages are saved. I found tables for blogentries, bookmarks or directories, but I couldn't find the table for communty pages? Are they even saved in the database, or are they just files on the filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is called Layout.

Also of relevance is LayoutSet and Group.

Web Content data on pages can be found on JournalArticle (and other tables that begin with Journal).

Comment: Where is the actual content of the community page. I can only find metadata. I know it must be somewhere in the database, because when i migrated the database to another machine with liferay, the pages were imported. So it can't be a file on the filesystem.

Comment: Pages themselves only store data about the portlets on them. If you're speaking of "Web Content" try the JournalArticle table.